# Regenerating slugs in Doctrine1

Tags: symfony1

Is there any good way to generate slugs for existing data if we migrate a field in database table to slugable using Doctrine1 and Symfony 1.4?

One way is to loop through all database entries and update the field to generate a slug. But is there any built-in function in Doctrine1 to re-generate slugs just like we use batchUpdateIndex() function to update search index in Doctrine1?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by regenerate slugs? Are you referring to the a slug in the view component of symfony or something else?

Comment: @Jestep, consider you have a database table with some data that has not any slugable field. but later you upgrade a field to slugable through doctrine migrations. Doctrine will add another column in that table with NULL data. Slugs will be created for only new inserts in that table. I wanted to know is there any good way to generate slugs for existing data.